Положить дополнительные компоненты в инсталятор приложения Visual Studio
Имею небольшое приложение написанное на C# с использованием LocalDB. Понимаю что обычно так не делается но для курсового проекта требования именно такие. При создании инсталятора путём использования Visual Studio, я так же предлагаю пользователю докачать необходимую версию .Net и LocalDB. Всё бы ничего, но вот на компьютере пользователя(в учебном заведении) нет интернет подключения. Таким образом мне необходимо вшить в инсталятор файлы со своего ПК.
При попытки сборки выдаётся ошибка что компоненты на моём ПК отсутствуют, но нет никаких подсказок где их скачать и куда их расположить, для того чтобы Visual Studio смог их записать в инсталятор. Прошу помощи!
Прилагаю изображение выбора компонентов установки.

Требуется установить .Net 4.7.2(или выше)
Требуется установить SQL Server 2019 Express LocalDB


